# How to handle font disposing in custom control?

Tags: c#, winforms, fonts, gdi+

Disposing of [Fonts](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Drawing/commonui/System/Drawing/Advanced/Font.cs,7c692e253eb24b01) seems a bit weird to me. If I for example have a label control and dispose the font it uses like `label1.Font.Dispose();` it still draws fine.

If I instead try to use a disposed font immediately it fails, e.g.

```
var f = new Font("Arial", 14);
f.Dispose();
g.DrawString("Hello", f, Brushes.Black, 20, 20);
```

with the exception `Invalid parameter`.

The latter seems more intuitive to me, given that I am trying to use a disposed font.
I can't understand why the label still draws fine, because in the [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Label.cs,383ce8908859a097) of the label I can see that the font is just used immediately without any checking: `e.Graphics.DrawString(Text, Font, brush, face, stringFormat);`.

The background of the question is, that I have a custom control that - like other controls - uses fonts as properties and implements `IDisposable`. I am now wondering if I should dispose of the font properties, because I can't know if e.g. the font property was set to a font that is still needed.

`Control` seems to use some `FontHandleWrapper` class internally which I don't quite understand to be honest. <strike>But even if I dispose a font in my custom control (which I have in an external library) from the outside it still paints fine, and I use the fonts immediately there.</strike>

Can someone explain why I can dispose one font and not the other?
Should I leave the fonts alone in the Dispose method of my custom control or dispose them?

Comment: The Font used directly is the Font assigned to the `Font`  property of a Control. The old Font is disposed of when the Font is changed: [Control.OnFontChanged](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/Control.cs,8174). If **you** create a disposable object, then dispose of it in-place when you're done with it. If the Font object is something that needs to persist, dispose of it in the `Dispose(bool disposing)` method.

Comment: The `FontHandleWrapper` takes care of the current Font handle and creates/disposes of the handle (`DeleteObject(new HandleRef(this, handle)) => [gdi32].IntDeleteObject(HandleRef hObject)`) when needed. There's also a default Font feature, a Font-Fallback feature (...)

Comment: Ok, it's still quite complicated when it comes to details, like that I initialize the properties with a new font (--> I should dispose them) but they may be set from the outside as well (--> I shouldn't dispose them). I'll look more into it. I ran into problems when a function created lots of these controls and by not disposing the fonts I guess I ran out of handles or something like that.

Comment: You don't actually need to dispose of the Font if you set it to the Font property. It's handled internally. Make a test, repeatedly setting the Font property of a Control to a random `new Font()` with the Diagnostic Tool and a TaskManager view of the applicaton resources opened. You'll see that you're not actually leaking Handles and/or Objects. You'll notice a small increase in memory usage. Then do the test disposing of the Font. Make a comparison.